# EF Core - Rewrite/Modify queries before sending to SQL Server or other providers

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to do such a thing?
I could do it with IDbCommandInterceptor. An example of use is this http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch

I found something about dependency injection but I could not find any examples and it seems to be related to an EF Core provider not to all providers.
I need to do it on EF not on a specific provider.

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/features)

Comment: Found anything?